# Verifying the correctness of a Kalman Filter implementation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, kalman-filter

Going with the theme of my recent posts I have implemented a Kalman Filter in an effort to get an ARIMA(p, q) implementation of my own up and running. I apologize, this question is rather subjective I'm sure.

I have gotten the Kalman Filter running but I don't know how to verify it is correctly implemented. It seems the pedagogy suggests that you graph the function, the observations, and the predicted observation from the kalman filter and check goodness of fit. This is fine for manual verification, however I would like to programmatically check on the effectiveness of my implementation.

Currently I have simulated 40 observations from a Gaussian Normal $N(0, 0.1)$, and added them to a constant $1$ to get some simulated "observation" data with noise.

I'm feeding these in and watching the algorithm process it, and by $t=40$ the algorithm seems to converge pretty close to the constant $1$, ($0.96$ or so to be exact). So I'm inclined to think it works on this toy example.

However, I don't trust that result. "Pretty close" needs to be defined quantitatively to make me feel comfortable with this implementation. Is there a recommended statistical test to check the effectiveness of the Kalman Filter in general?

Comment: There are many well-verified implementations of Kalman filters, so the easiest thing might be to use one of those as the "ground truth".

Comment: What do you mean by "effectiveness"? Are you asking about testing whether you have correctly implemented the filter or about testing whether your model is adequate?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I mean about implementing it correctly.

Comment: Closely related (if not duplicate): http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40466